# PHPCrawl cookies / password authentication

Tags: php, authentication, cookies, web-crawler, phpcrawl

I have a question about PHPCrawl for crawling a password protected site for which I have a password.

So, I have the crawler that works for websites that do not need authentication. The crawler I execute from the terminal (ubuntu 14.04). But when I try to use it on a website that needs username and password it doesn't work. I tried `PHPCrawl->addBasicAuthentication` but it didn't help. 
Then, I had the following idea - call the crawler from the browser, after first I had opened a tab in which the website I want to crawl is opened and I am logged in.

But I assume that PHPCrawl is not aware of the authentication session. 
So, my question is: Does anyone have an idea how to make PHPCrawl aware that I am logged in and crawl the website without problems?